# Change of Base - Tensor Product of Fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, tensor-products

Let $T$, $S$, and $X$ be indeterminates, and suppose we have the relation $S^3 = T$ so that $S = \sqrt[3]{T}$. Suppose we want to compute

$$\mathbb{F}_4(\sqrt[3]{T}) \otimes_{\mathbb{F}_4(T)} \mathbb{F}_4(\sqrt[3]{T})$$

and check whether this $\mathbb{F}_4(T)$-algebra is a field, or a product of fields. Apparently, the following is true:

$$\mathbb{F}_4(\sqrt[3]{T}) \otimes_{\mathbb{F}_4(T)} \mathbb{F}_4(\sqrt[3]{T}) = \mathbb{F}_4(S) \otimes_{\mathbb{F}_4(T)} \mathbb{F}_4(S) \cong \mathbb{F}_4(S) \otimes_{\mathbb{F}_4(T)} \frac{\mathbb{F}_4[X]}{(X^3-T)} \color{red}{\cong} \frac{\mathbb{F}_4(S)[X]}{(X^3-T)} = \frac{\mathbb{F}_4(S)[X]}{(X^3-S^3)}$$

I don't understand why the red isomorphism holds. My impression is that we are using some kind of base change formula like

$$B \otimes_A A[X]/I \cong B[X]/I$$

but that's not the same as what we have here. Is there some other base change formula that is being used?

The following is related, but doesn't answer the question:

[About expressing algebras like tensor products as a cartesian product of fields](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3797018/about-expressing-algebras-like-tensor-products-as-a-cartesian-product-of-fields)

Comment: $\frac{\mathbb{F}_4[X]}{(X^3-T)}$ has no meaning. Where is $T$ living in that object?

Comment: Good point. That would resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\mathbb{F}_4(\sqrt[3]{T}) \otimes_{\mathbb{F}_4(T)} \mathbb{F}_4(\sqrt[3]{T}) = \mathbb{F}_4(S) \otimes_{\mathbb{F}_4(T)} \mathbb{F}_4(S) \cong \mathbb{F}_4(S) \otimes_{\mathbb{F}_4(T)} \frac{\mathbb{F}_4(T)[X]}{(X^3-T)} \cong \left(\mathbb{F}_4(S) \otimes_{\mathbb{F}_4(T)} \mathbb{F}_4(T)[X]\right)\otimes_{\mathbb{F}_4(T)[X]}\frac{\mathbb{F}_4(T)[X]}{(X^3-T)}\stackrel{(*)}\cong \mathbb F_4(S)[X]\otimes_{\mathbb F_4(T)[X]}\frac{\mathbb{F}_4(T)[X]}{(X^3-T)}\stackrel{(**)}\cong \frac{\mathbb{F}_4(S)[X]}{(X^3-T)} = \frac{\mathbb{F}_4(S)[X]}{(X^3-S^3)}$$

I have used $B\otimes_AA[X]\simeq B[X]$ in $(*)$ and  $B\otimes_AA/I\simeq B/IB$ in $(**)$.

Comment: Since $\mathbb F_4^\times$ is a cyclic group, there exists $\alpha\in\mathbb F_4$ such that $\mathrm{ord}(\alpha)=3$, that is, $\mathbb F_4$ contains a primitive $3$rd root of unity. Then $X^3−S^3$ splits over $\mathbb F_4(S)$ and the given tensor product is isomorphic with the direct product of three copies of $\mathbb F_4(S)$.

Comment: Thank you so much!